# How can I test my Sails.js model's unique email attribute with Wolfpack.js?

Tags: javascript, mocking, sails.js, sinon, stub

I'm using Wolfpack.js to avoid having to 'lift' my Sails and I am running into an issue of not having a database to test my 'unique' attribute requirement against.  I tried to just fire the request twice, but with how it fakes the DB, I can't seem to ADD stuff to that fake db...  How can I test my model's requirement without having a database?  Is there a way to 'fake' my database's 'duplicate key' response so my model can trigger the 'unique' requirement and return an error to my test?

my model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      required: true,
      notEmpty: true,
      unique: true
    },
    ...
  }

};
```

my test:

```
it('should return `already exists` error when email already exists', function (done) {
    User.create({ email: 'test@example.com', password: 'P4$sword1234' }, function (err, user) {
      should.exist(err);
      err.message.should.have.string('that `email` already exists');
      should.not.exist(user);

      done();
    });
  });
```

Is this the best way to do this?  Am I completely on the wrong track? Also, should i be testing for the strings of error messages returned from Sails.js's own validations?  I was worried about how I should tell the controller about the errors coming from the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to test errors with wolfpack is to use the `setErrors` method: https://github.com/fdvj/wolfpack#mocking-errors

I wrote these articles as well explaining how to use Wolfpack in more complex applications:
https://fernandodevega.com/en/2015/12/19/functional-testing-a-sailsjs-api-with-wolfpack-part-3/

So in your case, in your setup, you can do something like this

```
User.setErrors('that `email` already exists');
User.create({ email: 'test@example.com', password: 'P4$sword1234' }, function (err, user) {
  should.exist(err);
  err.message.should.have.string('that `email` already exists');
  should.not.exist(user);

  done();
});
```